# 403 forbidden error on magento after a host crash

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento

I have looked extensively through all of the answers on here and currently tried adjusting all of my file and directory permissions to be 6,4,4 and 7,5,5 respectively and also tried to replace and alter all of the `.htaccess` files in many different ways but I still cannot get to the standard front page or admin login page after a crash after trying to do something with `m2e pro` and it did not go through.

I read in one of the other threads that it was potentially that my shared host provider was stopping the `index.php` file from running because it was taking too many resources. Is there any way to test for this? I have opened a support ticket with my host (sitegrounds) in order to simply wipe my server `vm` because I had very little on there as I had just installed for the first time and gotten `m2e pro` setup. I looked through the error log as the 403 page stated for a more specific reason and the only thing in there was

```
[Tue May 31 22:45:09.079809 2016] [:error] [pid 10353] [client 66.87.65.227:34727] script not found or unable to stat: /home/*sitename*/public_html/index.php
```

Any potential solutions for this or should I just wait for my system to be wiped? It'll save me a couple hours of setup if I don't have to make my policies and associate my accounts again.